# Escaped Periods In R Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, r

Unless I am missing something, this regex seems pretty straightforward:

```
grepl("Processor\.[0-9]+\..*Processor\.Time", names(web02))
```

However, it doesn't like the escaped periods, `\.` for which my intent is to be a literal period:

```
Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "Processor\."
```

What am I misunderstanding about this regex syntax?

Comment: I don't know R but have your tried `\\.`?

Comment: @mu: Ya, that fixes it. But wonder exactly why I need the double `\` to escape it

Comment: You need one to escape the other so that you get one past the string mangler and through to the regex engine.

Comment: @Mu: Okay that makes sense now that I read http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

My R-Fu is weak to the point of being non-existent but I think I know what's up.

The string handling part of the R processor has to peek inside the strings to convert `\n` and related escape sequences into their character equivalents. R doesn't know what `\.` means so it complains. You want to get the escaped dot down into the regex engine so you need to get a single `\` past the string mangler. The usual way of doing that sort of thing is to escape the escape:

```
grepl("Processor\\.[0-9]+\\..*Processor\\.Time", names(web02))
```

Embedding one language (regular expressions) inside another language (R) is usually a bit messy and more so when both languages use the same escaping syntax.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of

```
\.
```

Try

```
\\.
```

You need to escape the backspace first.

Answer (score 5):

The R-centric way of doing this is using the `[::]` notation, for example:

```
grepl("[:.:]", ".")
# [1] TRUE
grepl("[:.:]", "a")
# [1] FALSE
```

From the docs (`?regex`):

> The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?, but note that whether these have a special meaning depends on the context.

> [:punct:]
> Punctuation characters:
> ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~.

Comment: Thanks! The `pattern = "blabla\\."` didn't work for me but `"blabla[:.:]"` did.