# Match period with Regex in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr, magrittr

A trivial regex operation in R, but even the [other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638072/escaped-periods-in-r-regular-expressions) which appear relevant aren't helping me

I have a list of csv files names--

```
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)


set.seed("43212")

foo <- c(raply(3, 
          sample(letters, 3, T) %>% 
            paste0(collapse = "")),
         raply(3, 
          sample(0:9, 3, T) %>% 
            paste0(collapse = ""))) %>% 
         str_c(".csv") 

foo
[1] "hoo.csv" "wwc.csv" "lll.csv" "406.csv" "120.csv" "362.csv"
```

I want to extract the `.csv` files whose name end with some number, and exclude the filenames which end with a character.

I thought I understood regex and escaped characters in R--but this:

```
foo %>% 
  extract(str_sub(., -5) == "\\d\\.csv")
```

fails--what am I missing?

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: was using those three packages and using that code to get `foo <- c("hoo.csv", "wwc.csv", "lll.csv", "406.csv", "120.csv", "362.csv")` really necessary for your question?

Comment: I'm deeply unimaginative =0(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use grep.

```
grep("\\d\\.csv$", x, value=T)
```

or

```
grep("[[:digit:]]\\.csv$", x, value=T)
```

Comment: Instead of using the escaped \\. you can also use [.] e.g. grep("[[:digit:]][.]csv$",x,value=T).