# Simple regex in R escape "Mr\\."

Tags: r, regex

I know that this question looks identical to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638072/escaped-periods-in-r-regular-expressions), but I still can't get my expression to run. I'm trying to locate "Mr." and using the regular expression "Mr\." to do so. Here is the full line of code:

```
HPText$text<-str_replace(string = HPText$text, pattern= "Mr\\.", replacement 
= "Mister")
```

Can't wait to find out what stupid mistake I'm making.

Comment: What is the result you expect? Your `str_replace` does replace a single `Mr.` with `Mister`. Why use a regex here, BTW? You may use a fixed search for that. If you need to replace all occurrences of `Mr.` with `Mister`, use `str_replace_all(HPText$text, fixed("Mr."), "Mister")`.

Comment: `str_replace(string = c("Mr. Jones", "Jones, Mr."), pattern= "Mr\\.", replacement = "Mister")` works fine. Please create a reproducible example with input, expected output and where in your case it doesn't return what you expect.

Comment: strng<-"In an instant he had pull Mr. Weasley and Mr. Malfoy apart. strng<-str_replace(string = strng, pattern= "(Mr\\.)", replacement = "Mister")
> strng
[1] "In an instant he had pull Mister Weasley and Mr. Malfoy apart." Sorry, terrible formatting. It's working inconsistently. I'm at a loss. @phiver

Comment: You just need to replace all occurrences, `str_replace_all(HPText$text, fixed("Mr."), "Mister")` as I mention in my top comment.

Comment: Got it, thank you!