# What is the meaning of " \\." in tidyr::separate?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

what is the purpose of " \. " and why it is quoted?
this is the code:

```
library(tidyr)

iris.tidy <- iris %>%
  gather(key, Value, -Species) %>%
  separate(key, c("Part", "Measure"), "\\.")
```

it is for the iris dataset

Comment: iris dataset 

https://gist.github.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7#file-iris-csv

Comment: You don't need meaning of `"\\."` in R but meaning of `"\\."` in `separate` specifically. Read `?separate`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6638072/680068 We need to escape the escape character.

Comment: I'm not understanding the word key in the separate function, since we're using a pipe, the data argument precedes the function and we don't mention it as first arg, so our first arg with seperate() is col, which is column name or position, the thing is the whole iris dataset does NOT have a column named key!

Comment: Column name `key` comes from `gather` where you do `gather(key, Value, -Species)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to understand if you run the code step by step.

`gather` brings the data in long format with column `key` with column names and column `value` with values of those columns

```
library(tidyr)

iris %>% gather(key, Value, -Species) %>%  head

#  Species          key Value
#1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
#2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
#3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
#4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
#5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
#6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
```

We then use `separate` to divide `key` column in two columns based on `"."` in their text.

```
iris %>%
  gather(key, Value, -Species) %>%
  separate(key, c("Part", "Measure"), "\\.") %>% head

#  Species  Part Measure Value
#1  setosa Sepal  Length   5.1
#2  setosa Sepal  Length   4.9
#3  setosa Sepal  Length   4.7
#4  setosa Sepal  Length   4.6
#5  setosa Sepal  Length   5.0
#6  setosa Sepal  Length   5.4
```

Since the `sep` argument in `separate` accepts regex and `.` has a special meaning in regex, if we want to specify actual `.` we need to escape it, hence we use `"\\."`. Also note that `gather` has been replaced with `pivot_longer` in the newer version of `tidyr`.

Comment: that's the type of explanation I'm looking for exactly, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`.` says every character (in a regular expression). If you actually wan't it as a `"."` (the character itself) you need to "escape" it with a `\` which however is a special character in regular expressions as well and therefore also needs to be escaped.